# What did Charlie Sheen mean when he used the phrase "banging 7 gram rocks"?

Tags: phrases

Today’s Quote of Time.com (TIME@time.chtah.com) carries the following line of Charlie Sheen’s remark. Being totally ignorant of the background of CBS and Warner Brothers’ cancellation of the production of the program, I have no idea about the phrase, ‘bang 7 gram rock.’

I understand the line after ‘Because that’s how I roll ...’ means he is single-mindedly do what he decided to do – to sue CBC and Warner Broth. Can somebody translate the above line into English easier for a foreign learner like me to understand?

> "I probably took more than anybody
>   could survive. I was banging 7 gram
>   rocks. Because that's how I roll. I
>   have one speed. I have one gear: Go." 
>   CHARLIE SHEEN, who on Monday night, in
>   addition to giving incoherent
>   interviews, announced that he plans to
>   sue CBS and Warner Brothers for
>   canceling the production of Two and a
>   Half Men.”

Comment: On a humorous note: on the radio this morning, the host was running a phone-in contest where people had to decide whether a quotation they read was said by Charlie Sheen or Muaamar Quadafi. Very few people won a prize. Charlie says all kinds of crazy things. (looks like they were reading this: http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/quiz/2011/mar/01/muammar-gaddafi-charlie-sheen-quiz )

Comment: Curious use of speed and gear in the last sentence, which have both a double meaning, on the one hand related to drugs and on the other to driving...

Comment: This is the second Google result for "banging 7 gram rocks," a phrase you don't hear very often and gives you pause to decipher.  No wonder this question has so many views ;)

Comment: You'd think more people could vote some of our answers up.... ;-)

Comment: I took the "Qaddafi or Sheen?" quiz today. I scored...well, let's just say way under 50 percent correct. Way under.

Comment: @Hellion I think this probably a good thing for the site.  Yoichi has inadvertently popped our site into sphere of a pop culture phenomenon like Charlie Sheen...better than a Digg plug, IMO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

taking it a sentence at a time:

> I probably took more than anybody could survive.
>
> -> I did so many drugs I should have died [from an overdose].
>
> I was banging 7 gram rocks
>
> -> I was taking 7 grams of hard drugs [crack cocaine, probably] at a time.
>
> That's how I roll.
>
> -> That's the way I am.
>
> I have one speed.  I have one gear: Go.
>
> -> I take chances, I take risks, I don't care about the negatives.

Comment: I'd argue that "I have one speed. I have one gear: Go." would be more aligned with "I don't wait around; I'm ambitious and will constantly move forward (in life)...good or bad"

Comment: I'd argue the whole thing can be parsed as "Don't do Crack!"

Comment: 7 gram rocks? That is enough to kill Two and a Half Men.

Comment: @user6751: Would that that were true.

Answer (score 30):

> Banging 7-gram rocks.

He's talking about taking ("banging") crystals of [crack cocaine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crack_cocaine). Seven grams is a LOT. According to the Wikipedia article, "Large amounts (several hundred milligrams or more) intensify the user's high, but may also lead to bizarre, erratic, and violent behavior." If a large dose is less than a gram, one wonders how Mr. Sheen survived at all.

> That's how I roll.

Slang for "this is my normal, customary behavior."

> I have one speed and one gear: go.

If he is moving at all, he is moving at his maximum speed.

Answer (score 3):

"Banging" means injecting, snorting or smoking cocaine. He probably sniffed a ton of coke, I can't see Charlie being a crackhead. Cocaine, as we all know, is very common in Hollywood.

He's been on the stuff for years.

Over time, he probably needed to do more to get high (obviously). I'd say doing seven grams at a time is insane, but I think he meant he did seven grams in a sitting, or a night, and it was nothing to him.

How's that for translation?